# Mysql-server Error

Tags: tuleap, mysql5

I install all package on virtual machine.I have centos 6.6 and I already installed "mysqld Ver 5.6.24 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))".I have installed the tuleap on centos 6.6.Sucessfully installed without error.

But when I use:

```
/usr/share/tuleap-install/setup.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
**ERROR** No --mysql-host nor local mysql server installed, exit.
Please install 'mysql-server' package"
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the install script only check for `mysql-server` package from centos 6 base.

To install with another version of mysql, you should start the database and use `--mysql-host=localhost` as if you installed on a remote machine

Comment: No I install all package on virtual machine.I have centos 6.6 and I already installed "mysqld  Ver 5.6.24 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))".if I using "/usr/share/tuleap-install/setup.sh" this command,It shows "**ERROR** No --mysql-host nor local mysql server installed, exit.
Please install 'mysql-server' package"...I cant resolve it.help me to solve it..

Comment: As said, the install script rely on `mysql-server` (v5.1) package to be present. You installed another version (mysqld v 5.6.24), that's perfectly fine but you have to specify that to the install script with `--mysql-host`

Comment: please let me know how to start Database using --mysql-host=localhost

Kindly give me the steps

Answer (score 0):

Well, this error has occured to me and I corrected it by doing as @Manuel said.

Before running the setup.sh I uninstalled the old mysql server I was using. Then I run this command again:

```
yum install --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras tuleap-all
```

Which installed the "right" version of mysql-server. After that, you should run this:

```
/usr/share/tuleap-install/setup.sh --mysql-host=localhost
```